# Dropwizard and Fileupload using angularJS with multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, dropwizard

I am noob in Dropwizard and angularJs and trying to use file upload using DropWizard and AngularJs (in front). My use case is as follows : 
A wizard like interface with Steps such that Steps 1 will ask for user to upload 2 files, then Step 2 will ask for user to provide 2 inputs (text field) and click validate.

I used 3 controllers for this :
1. MainController (in the body) used to create an explainer using angularJs [ngDialog script](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog).
2. Upload Controller inside Maincontroller to upload files.
3. Validate Controller to take input from user to validate the text.

For some reason I could not make it to work to a point that i decided to use different framework now. This would be my last try.  Below is some code snippets

```
<head>
.....
.....    
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"/>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/ngDialog.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myValidatorApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
       <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" ng-click="open()" class="demo">Explainer</a>
        <a href="#step1" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Go to Step 1</a>               
       </div>
    </div>
<!-- Step 1 -->
<section id="step1" class="services bg-section" ng-controller="UploadCtrl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
          <h2>Step 1 - Upload Weight Data</h2>
          <form id="fileupload1" action="/service/upload/weight" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
            <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <span>
                    <span>Upload Weight data</span>
                </span>
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add File...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="WeightData" multiple ng-disabled="disabled">
                </span>
                <span>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" ng-click="upload('modulus')">
                     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                     <span>Start upload</span>
                 </button>
                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fade" data-ng-class="{in: active()}">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" data-file-upload-progress="progress()">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <form id="fileupload2" action="/upload/sortcode" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
            <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <span>
                    <span>Upload Substitution data</span>
                </span>
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add File...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="sortcodeData" multiple ng-disabled="disabled">
                </span>
             <span>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" ng-click="upload('sortcode')">
                     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                     <span>Start upload</span>
                 </button>
             </span>    
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fade" data-ng-class="{in: active()}">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" data-file-upload-progress="progress()">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
          </form>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <div align="center">
        <a href="#step2" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Go to Step 2</a>
    </div>  
</section>
<!-- Validation -->

<section id="#step2" class="services bg-section" ng-controller="ValidateCtrl">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
             <h2>Step 2 - Provide Sortcode and AccountNumber</h2>
             <div class="row">
               <form name="userForm" novalidate>
                    <!-- sortcode field -->
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.sortcode.$touched && userForm.sortcode.$invalid }">
                        <label>Sort Code (6 digit)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sortcode" class="form-control" ng-model="main.sortcode" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="6" required>
                        <!-- ngMessages goes here -->
                        <p ng-show="userForm.sortcode.$error.empty" class="message-block">Sortcode is required.</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.sortcode.$error.minlength" class="message-block">Sortcode is too short.</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.sortcode.$error.minlength" class="message-block">Sortcode is too long.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- account number field -->
                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.accountnumber.$touched && userForm.accountnumber.$invalid }">
                        <label>Account Number (8 digit)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="accountnumber" class="form-control" ng-model="main.accountnumber" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="8" required>
                        <!-- ngMessages goes here -->
                        <p ng-show="userForm.accountnumber.$invalid && !userForm.accountnumber.$pristine" class="message-block">Account Number is required.</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.accountnumber.$error.minlength" class="message-block">Account Number is too short</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.accountnumber.$error.minlength" class="message-block">Account Number is too long.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Validate</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                </div>
             <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
         </div>
         <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
     </section>
```

My app.js

```
     var UploadCtrl = function ($scope, $http)
{
    var serviceURI = "/service/";
    $scope.upload = function(uploadType) {
            if(uploadType == "modulus"){
                var response = $http.post('/service/upload/modulusweight', $scope.jsonObj);
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  $scope.resetSearch();
                  });

                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  alert("AJAX failed to get data, status=" + status);
                });  
            } else if(uploadType == "sortcode"){
                var response = $http.post('/service/upload/sortcode', $scope.jsonObj);
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  $scope.resetSearch();
                  });

                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  alert("AJAX failed to get data, status=" + status);
                });  
            }
        }
};
```

My FileUploadResource.java

```
@Path("/upload")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class FileUploadResource {


    private String uploadPath;


    public FileUploadResource(String uploadPath) {
        this.uploadPath = uploadPath;
    }


    @Path("/modulusweight")
    @POST
    @Timed
    @UnitOfWork
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart form) {

         FormDataBodyPart filePart = form.getField("modulusWeightData");

         ContentDisposition headerOfFilePart =  filePart.getContentDisposition();

         InputStream fileInputStream = filePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);

         String filePath = uploadPath +"/"+ headerOfFilePart.getFileName();

        // save the file to the server
        saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

        String output = "File saved to server location using FormDataMultiPart : " + filePath;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    // save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
    private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String serverLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();
            uploadedInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And everytime I click on button nothing happens.
But when I use postman to send request directly I get error like

```
{
  "code": 415,
  "message": "HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"
}
```

This is different issue. I am more interested to know why button clicks are not working.

Comment: Did you set a media type in your request on the angular side? It appears that jersey does not know how to treat the body you are passing it.

Comment: @pandaadb did you mean enctype="multipart/form-data" in form I am doing it, or you mean in the app.js where I am using $http.post ? But my worry is that why button click don't work from form ? This error about unsupported media type is only from postman.

Comment: I am not very familiar with angularJs, but this is the kind of response when your server rejects your post, because it doesn't know what to do. Can you edit the question and append the entire request made. It sounds to me like the content-type header is not set correctly. You can use curl to manually test your endpoint and see if your Dropwizard Resource accepts the request, to narrow down what is going wrong.